# Regular expression for live validation of phone numbers including x

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I am using regEx `/^[0-9]+(x|X){0,1}[0-9]*?$/g` this is working fine for `nth number of digits + x +  nth number of digits`.

But I want to - `10 digits + x + 5 digits`.

[Stackblitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/regular-expression-for-live-validation-of-phone-numbers-includi?file=src/app/phone-number.directive.ts)

Example - `1234567890x12345`

So please provide me regEx for above example to prevent user to enter nth number of digits.

*Valid inputs:*

```
1234567890
1234567890x1
1234567890X1
1234567890x12345
```

*Invalid inputs:*

```
12345678901
1234567890x123456
1234567890X123456
```

Comment: What country's phone-number format are you wanting to match?

Comment: Is it 10 and 5 fixed? Or up to 10 and up to 5?

Comment: Every regex tutorial will tell you how to do this. The solution is also already in your regular expression. You just have to slightly adjust it.

Comment: How are you using the regex? It looks as if you are using it for live text input validation. Try `^[0-9]{1,10}(?:[xX][0-9]{0,5})?$`

Comment: @CinCout yes it's fixed 10 and 5

Comment: Does it mean the `12345678901` is invalid format?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes

Comment: So, your initial regex was NOT working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure a user can type only a valid string in the input field you need a regex for live validation like

```
^[0-9]{1,10}(?:[xX][0-9]{0,5})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tn0FUx/1)

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]{1,10}` - one to ten digits (change to `{0,10}` to also allow an empty string)
- `(?:[xX][0-9]{0,5})?` - an optional sequence of

  - `[xX]` - an `x` or `X`
  - `[0-9]{0,5}` - zero to five digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: How can i add validation 10 digit compulsory before x and 1 digit after x ?

Comment: @KrishnaRathore A lot depends on how you perform this check, but when you need to **match** ten digits, you should use `[0-9]{10}`. To match one, two, three, four or five digits, you use `[0-9]{1,5}`. Does that help? Note that you might want another regex for *final* (or I call it *on-submit*) validation: `^[0-9]{10}[xX][0-9]{5}$` - it will match a string that starts with 10 digits, then has an `x` and then 5 digits.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go: ^[0-9]{10}(x|X){0,1}[0-9]{5}?$

Comment: That will not help with live input validation as it will only match the whole input format. Also, `[0-9]{5}?` = `[0-9]{5}`, this is a clear user error

Comment: But post nowhere mentions it's needed for live validation.

Comment: There is a hint, look at the regex that is working for OP and that matches `1x` kind of input.

Comment: Now, the title mentions live validation.